# Is Gatchaman Crowds set in the same universe as Gatchaman?

Tags: gatchaman, gatchaman-crowds

I read about the upcoming **Gatchaman Crowds** anime.

According to [this source](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2013-04-16/gatchaman-crowds-anime-characters-staff-revealed), the series is about

> "Gatchaman" — warriors who fight in special reinforced suits powered
>   by "NOTE," the manifestation of special spiritual powers in living
>   beings.

This surprised me - the original Gatchaman series had no supernatural material. Some pretty improbable things happened, but they were all understood to be advanced science & technology. The "Bird Go!" transformations were not spiritual but technological.

So, is Gatchaman Crowds set in the same universe as the original Gatchaman?

Note: I'm aware this can't be answered until the show starts, or until Tatsunoko reveals more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer to this, but based on the first 2 episodes of *Gatchaman Crowds* (all that has aired so far), at the very least there's no clear connection between the two series. If they are in the same universe, the characters in the two series don't seem to be interacting at all. There are definitely references to the original series, e.g. all of the members of the *Gatchaman* team in the original series have counterparts in *Gatchaman Crowds*, and many of the concepts stayed the same.

There's good reason to believe that the two series are in different universes. In the original Gatchaman, all of their powers were, at least in principle, just the product of science and technology. In *Gatchaman Crowds*, by contrast, their powers are of some sort of mystic origin. It's not yet clear how they work, but they aren't purely within the realm of science fiction anymore. This rendition of *Gatchaman* is thus fundamentally different from the original, and probably only makes sense in its own universe.

The Wikipedia entry for [*Gatchaman Crowds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatchaman#Gatchaman_Crowds) seems to agree with this, describing *Gatchaman Crowds* as “based in the Gatchaman universe,” which would seem to preclude it from being in the same universe. However, there's no solid source for that statement, so it's at best questionable.

Of course, this answer could still change (at least until *Gatchaman Crowds* ends) but for the moment it seems more likely that they are in different universes.

Comment: I've waited a while with accepting this until more episodes were available. By now it's safe to say this answer is right.

Comment: I would refute the "mystic origin" part as speculation, with this razor: "Any sufficient advanced technology..." - when Katze forcibly removes Hibiki's note, there is a lot of wiring behind it. And JJ is not telling how he does his stuff. But you are correct that it is not pure science fiction as in SF they at least try to make some kind of explanation to the tech.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the connection between *Gatchaman Crowds* and the original *Gatchaman* is the original is a TV show in the *Gatchaman Crowds* universe in which somehow the team actually exists in the world, which would explain the references to the team in the first episode before the reveal of them actually existing.

Comment: I don't think there was a "Gatchaman" TV show in the Crowds universe. Was a TV show mentioned in that first episode? IIRC The existence of Gatchamans was a rumor - something you'd find in tabloids or websites devoted to conspiracy theories.